# Where memory is allocated for valuetypes which are inside a class when object of the class is created

Tags: c#, .net

We know that value types are allocated memory in stack and reference types are allocated in heap. Now when we create an object of a class it's a reference type and memory will be allocated in heap,at this point I have a confusion where does values types in these class have memory allocated?? Is it heap or stack?

Comment: I went through [this explenation](http://www.albahari.com/valuevsreftypes.aspx) rather quickly but I think this could be helpfull for you.

Comment: Value types variables live where they are declared. If declared as fields of another type, they live *in* that type. If the value type variable is declared as a local variable of a method, then it will reside on the stack or in a register, depending on compiler optimization. If the value type variable is declared as a field of another value type, if that other type lives in a local variable of a method, the first value type will live inside that other value type variable on the stack or in a register, depending.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Value-types are created on the stack" is an oversimplification.

Value-types of variables *inside a method* exist in the stack instead of being a reference to an object on the heap.

Value-types of fields (inside a class or struct) exist as a contiguous memory region *inside* the parent type - so if the parent object exists on the stack then a value-type member will also exist in the stack, while a reference-type value will only have a reference/pointer on the stack.